# How to copy only the commit messages of Android Studio from log of Version Control

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control

[image]

When i block and copy those logs, it will copy the hash, committer, and time too. 
For example:

```
7e15726 hendrawd on 11/13/16 at 10:18 PM Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
a464db8 hendrawd on 11/13/16 at 10:16 PM fix ignored files
094ef35 Hendra Wijaya Djiono on 11/10/16 at 4:59 PM Swipe refresh will refresh notification count too
4759306 Hendra Wijaya Djiono on 11/10/16 at 12:51 PM Restructure
33ad61b Hendra Wijaya Djiono on 11/10/16 at 12:46 PM Fix force closed when crop picture on create group
8763667 Hendra Wijaya Djiono on 11/9/16 at 7:02 PM Fix duplicate notification
```

I don't remember when it was implemented, maybe in Android Studio 2.2. It used to be just copy commit messages.

So how i can get only commit messages? Because i just need that instead of the full detail and it is very inconvenience to edit the lines one by one to just get the commit messages.

My Android Studio version is:

```
Android Studio 2.3
Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no setting/button/checkbox to do what i want, the simplest way that i can do without the help of any external software/terminal is just to use regex to detect AM/PM(and a space after it) and replace all the characters before it(inclusive) with empty string directly.

Here are the steps:

1. Copy the logs
2. Create a scratch file(Command+Shift+N for Mac)
3. Paste the logs to the scratch file
4. Open Replace menu for the scratch file(Command+R for Mac)
5. Check Regex checkbox
6. Use this regex on the search box `.+?(?=(A|P)M\040)((A|P)M\040)`
7. Hit button Replace all

[image: example]

**To be noted, above method is unreliable. If we have commit message that contains string "AM " or "PM ", the previous string will automatically removed too. If IntelliJ decide to change again the copy format of the log, the regex will also be useless. So the best method is to use git command directly with terminal/command prompt**

Here is the example:

```
git log --since="2017-04-09" --pretty=format:"%s"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of idea you use. According to my test on my latest IDEA and WebStorm. I select in `log` tab of Version Control and copy and paste in Atom, I will get the commit message + name + time.

such as:

```
test message Xin Meng 31/03/17 11:10 
Merge branch 'feature' into develop Xin Meng 31/03/17 10:19 
kotlinc Xin Meng 31/03/17 10:19
```

if the output is above, you can use Atom(or other editor support Regex) to filter the other part.

Such as on Atom:

Ctrl+F and click `.*` in the Finding panel to enable Regex. And then put `Xin Meng.*` in the Finding input and replace with blank. Then click the Replace All.

Then all commit messages will be kept and the other things will be replaced with the blank.

Comment: Actually you can use intellij regex too directly without atom. Just make a scratch file, paste to it,  find and replace with the regex. But what i want to find here is the option to directly copy any field that i want to copy, like only commit messages for fast and convenience use

Comment: OK. you can use git directly to customize the export of git commit history: such as   `git log --since="last month" --pretty=format:'%s' > log.csv`  %s means only output the message. https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is not support to export the messages directly (no such button or setting). But you can use git command in **Terminal window** on android studio.